# Can not open local html file in browsers

Tags: html, browser, dreamweaver, tmp

I test my website page locally... after each modification with Dreamweaver, i open the html in Firefox to see the result. Since some days, after a while, i can not open the file nor with Firefox, neither with Chrome or Safari.

I saw .tmp files in my website files folder and they stayed there even after the actualisation of the folder. I deleted them.

There is a strange behaviour of my folder... when i refresh it, it seems that it does not finish charging, the green bar does not disappear (i am talking about PC Windows 7 folder behaviour).

Then i can not save my html anymore in Dreamweaver.

I cleaned up my computer with Spybot, Malwarebytes, Ccleaner and Avast.

My HTML codes :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9]><script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
<meta name="keywords" content="hongrie, immobilier, hébergement, maison à vendre, appartement, gîte, auberge, vacances, tourisme, économique, rustique, rural, paysage, confort, propre, hungary, real estate, house for sale, investment, lodge, apartment, room, guest house, accommodation, flat, vacation, tourism, randonner, gayfriendly, routard, backpacker, cheap, economic, rustic, traditional, countryside, landscape, cozy, comfort, clean, héviz, keszthely, zala, balaton, zalaegerszeg, sümeg, tapolca, ingatlan, szállás, üdülés, eladó ház, kiadó lakás, kiadó szoba, panzió, vidéki, falusi turizmus, túra" />
<meta name="description" content="West Hungary Com is a guide for the West Balaton region which proposes real estate for investors, and accommodations for tourists who are looking for a rural but comfortable environment." />
<meta name="robots" content="all" />
<meta name="revisit-after" content="15" />

<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="fa.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow|Raleway|Montserrat|Homemade+Apple|Shadows+Into+Light+Two" />
<!-- <link href="https://plus.google.com/101537360789263121987/" rel="publisher" /> must be changed to GIH's google page link -->

<title>West Hungary</title>
</head>

<body>

    <ul id="nav">
        <li id="fr">
            <div class="img2"><img src="img/lang-fr-hover.jpg" alt="nav fr" /></div>
            <div class="img1"><img src="img/lang-fr.jpg" alt="nav fr" /></div>
            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            <span class="lang-txt">Français ?</span>
        </li>
        <li id="en">
            <div class="img2"><img src="img/lang-en-hover.jpg" alt="nav en" /></div>
            <div class="img1"><img src="img/lang-en.jpg" alt="nav en" /></div>
            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span>
            <span class="lang-txt">English ?</span>
        </li>
        <li id="hu">
            <div class="img2"><img src="img/lang-hu-hover.jpg" alt="nav hu" /></div>
            <div class="img1"><img src="img/lang-hu.jpg" alt="nav hu" /></div>
            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            <span class="lang-txt">Magyar ?</span>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="content" id="francais">

        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="west hungary logo" /><h1>West Hungary</h1></div>            
            <div class="slider">
                <ul class="sb-slider">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">
                            <img src="img/slide1.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </a>
                        <div class="sb-description">
                            <h1>West Hungary</h1>
                            <p>West Hungary Com est un guide des sites à voir et des activités de la région de l'Ouest-Balaton, une catalogue d'immobiliers pour les investisseurs, et d'hébergements pour les touristes qui cherchent un environnement rural mais confortable. La région propose des vacances inoubliables et uniques.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">
                            <img src="img/slide15.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </a>
                        <div class="sb-description">
                            <h3>Hévìz</h3>
                            <p>Se baigner dans l'eau thermale chaude quand il fait froid et tout est blanc par la neige.</p>
                            <h3>Balaton</h3>
                            <p>Le lac Balaton se rechauffe à 26 degré aux étés méditerranéennes.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">
                            <img src="img/slide20.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </a>
                        <div class="sb-description">
                            <h3>Badacsony</h3>
                            <p>Sur la colline de Badacsony, le sol vulcanique se nourisse les vignes, la Hongrie est un pays des vins.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="shadow"></div>
                <div class="nav-arrows">
                    <a href="#">Next</a>
                    <a href="#">Previous</a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-dots">
                    <span class="nav-dot-current"></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <!--<div class="nav-options">
                    <span class="navPlay">Play</span>
                    <span class="navPause">Pause</span>
                </div>-->
            </div>       
            <div class="button-group">
                <label>Cherchez par sujet :</label>
                <button class="is-checked" data-filter="*">Tous</button>
                <button data-filter=".cat-info">Infos</button>
                <button data-filter=".cat-serv">Services</button>
                <button data-filter=".cat-accom">Hébergements</button>
                <button data-filter=".cat-immo">Immobiliers</button>
                <button data-filter=".cat-art">Art</button>
            </div>
            <button class="nav-call"><span class="fa fa-replay"></span></button>
        </div>

        <div class="section">

            <div class="box cat-info data">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="box-text">
                        <h2>Données</h2>
                        <p>Faites connaissance des informations de la région : population, géographie, statistiques.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-img">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="blog logo" />
                    </div>                    
                </a>
                <div class="hover"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="box cat-info transport">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="box-text">
                        <h2>Transport & Cartes</h2>
                        <p>Comment arriver à la région ? Réponse dans cette section...</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-img">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="transport logo" />
                    </div>                    
                </a>
                <div class="hover"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="box cat-info blog">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="box-text">
                        <h2>Events, Infos & News</h2>
                        <p>Pour lire les informations et nouvelles de la région, trouvez un endroit ou un évènement, une répresentation d'un produit ou d'une personne, tout est dans notre blog !</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-img">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="blog logo" />
                    </div>                    
                </a>
                <div class="hover"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="box box-2 cat-info activities">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="box-text">
                        <h2>Activités</h2>
                        <p>La région est internationalement connue grâce aux bains thermaux, son lac thermal, chaud l'été comme l'hiver, les plages du lac Balaton avec ces nombreuses fêtes et festivals. Le sol vulcanique et le climat subméditerranéen permettent de cultiver des vignes, la Hongrie est un pays viticole.</p>                      
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-img">
                        <img src="img-stup/logo.png" alt="stupapart logo" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-img">
                        <img src="img-stup/logo.png" alt="stupapart logo" />
                    </div>                    
                    <div class="box-text">
                        <p>Même si l'aéroport international de FlyBalaton ne reçoit que des charters de l'Allemagne, de la Suisse, de la Russie et de la Turquie, l'autoroute M7 offre une voie très rapide à partir de Budapest (2h) ou de la Slovénie et de Croatie. La mer Adriatique, une des plus belles côtes d'Europe se trouve 350 km du Balaton. Des trains et bus servent aussi un moyen de transport à la région.</p>
                    </div>                   
                </a>
                <div class="hover"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="box box-2 cat-accom stupapart">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="box-text">
                        <h2>StupApart</h2>
                        <p>Un beau gîte / appartement rustique et moderne à la fois, avec tout confort au coeur de la région, dans un village rural, quelques pas du Stupa - Centre de méditation de Zalaszanto et de nombreuses châteaux en ruines, à l'extremité ouest du Parc National de Haut-Balaton.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-img">
                        <img src="img/box-host1.jpg" alt="stupapart logo" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-img">
                        <img src="img/box-host2.jpg" alt="stupapart logo" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-text">
                        <p>Les plages de Balaton et le lac thermal de Héviz, le bain thermal et parc aquatique de Kehida et de Szent Groth, le centre le forteresse de Sümeg, la gouffre de Tapolca, les caves à vin de Badacsony, le théâtre et l'endroit de nombreuses festivals de Szigliget et Keszthely, le parc animalier de Zalaköveskút, les terrains de golf de Kehida et le lac des pêcheurs et pique-niqueurs à Zalacsany sont tous dans une distance de dizaines de kilomètres !</p>
                    </div>                    
                </a>
                <div class="hover"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="box cat-immo gaborimmo">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="box-text">
                        <h2>Gabor Immo</h2>
                        <p>Immobiliers pour les investisseurs qui voient l'intérêts d'acheter une maison de charactère ou un appartement pas cher, avec beaucoup de cachets où vous pouvez passer vos vacances en toute sérénité et avec nombreuses possibilités d'activité. L'équipe vous présente les immobiliers, travaille avec une avocate germano-anglophone, arrange les procédures administratives, conseille des artisanats pour des travaux et aide pour la gestion.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-img">
                        <img src="img-gab/logo.png" alt="gaborimmo logo" />
                    </div>                    
                </a>
                <div class="hover">
                    <a href="http://www.westhungary.com/gaborimmo.html">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-link fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="box cat-serv parabor">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="box-text">
                        <h2>Parabor</h2>
                        <p>Chaines en français à votre télé ! Vous n'êtes pas isolé, regardez la télé de votre maison hongroise en tout confort...</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-img">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="parabor logo" />
                    </div>                   
                </a>
                <div class="hover"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="box cat-serv architech">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="box-img">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="archi tech logo" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-text">
                        <h2>Archi Tech</h2>
                        <p>Agent constructeur pour les travaux de renovation et les nouvelles constructions. Tous travaux de bâtiment : toiture, maçonnerie, charpenterie : vitres - fênetres - portes, plomberie : chauffage - eau, electricité, isolation, peinture, décoration - design intérieur...</p> 
                    </div>                    
                </a>
                <div class="hover"></div>       
            </div>

            <div class="box cat-serv ildesign">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="box-img">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="il design logo" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-text">
                        <h2>IL Design</h2>
                        <p>Web-design francophone... faites une fênetre vers le monde, montrez votre vitrine aux publique international !</p>
                    </div>                   
                </a>
                <div class="hover">
                    <a href="http://webdesign.igorlaszlo.com">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-link fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="box cat-art ilart">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="box-img">
                        <img src="img/box-art.jpg" alt="il art" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-text">
                        <h2>IL Art</h2>
                        <p>Photographie d'art, mosaïques et peintures... artiste hongro-francophone de Vindornyalak !</p>
                    </div>                   
                </a>
                <div class="hover">
                    <a href="http://photography.igorlaszlo.com">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-link fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- end section (grid) -->

        <div class="page page-stupapart">
            <button class="back"><span class="fa fa-reply"></span></button>
            <img src="img/box-stupapart.jpg" alt="stupapart 1" />
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lacinia sapien metus, nec aliquet nisl imperdiet ultrices. Aliquam arcu risus, venenatis a tellus in, aliquam pulvinar sem. Aliquam ac posuere libero. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed nibh volutpat, aliquet eros fringilla, fermentum purus. In consectetur varius ornare. Maecenas ligula est, cursus tincidunt rutrum id, posuere ut massa. Phasellus suscipit lorem ut ultrices porttitor. Morbi sed tellus pulvinar, iaculis sem quis, ornare metus. Donec felis augue, interdum eget sapien molestie, consequat commodo turpis. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam tempus venenatis pharetra.

Praesent vehicula, mauris at ornare dignissim, eros nisi semper turpis, in efficitur purus risus eget mauris. Vivamus luctus dignissim venenatis. Suspendisse et porta arcu. Sed hendrerit tellus tempor enim efficitur interdum. In eu scelerisque leo. Donec et enim vitae metus fermentum viverra eu eu augue. Vestibulum a nulla et lacus dapibus finibus non at metus. Nullam sit amet porttitor nibh. Fusce finibus dictum massa, non scelerisque leo ultrices et. Ut at neque quis tortor consequat placerat eu eu lorem. Vivamus nec fermentum sapien, pretium dictum tortor. Cras risus libero, fringilla nec purus non, interdum lobortis ipsum. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse maximus, odio consequat consequat placerat, elit nulla sodales diam, nec sollicitudin nisl lorem in nibh.

Suspendisse sodales est quis nibh tempus tempus. Nam id lobortis risus, non lobortis dolor. Etiam porttitor scelerisque justo. Etiam pharetra elit vel augue commodo, non imperdiet nunc pulvinar. Sed eleifend metus vel eleifend posuere. Aenean elementum in mauris sit amet luctus. Fusce eget dignissim metus. Suspendisse sit amet ipsum eget nunc scelerisque eleifend.

Curabitur tincidunt magna sed libero pellentesque hendrerit. Mauris laoreet mattis tellus ut dapibus. Vestibulum fringilla accumsan arcu et sodales. Cras nibh mi, auctor eu congue at, egestas eu lectus. Nullam purus arcu, aliquet a dictum quis, fringilla ac dolor. Morbi tempus imperdiet nunc sed dignissim. Morbi tincidunt fermentum erat, sit amet sollicitudin justo.

Vivamus gravida sapien lacus, et congue mi congue at. Phasellus aliquet venenatis leo. Vivamus non tincidunt mauris. Ut blandit rutrum nisl, in semper felis. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque viverra ex est, et semper tellus fringilla in. Donec eros eros, euismod non molestie quis, luctus eget enim. Praesent tempus gravida dui, sit amet suscipit dui malesuada in. Vivamus posuere placerat est, sed feugiat magna malesuada non. Donec turpis nisi, convallis at neque vel, tempus varius metus.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="contact">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
            <p>Une question ? Une demande ? Un remarque ? Ecrivez nous et nous répondons...</p>
            <form id="contactform" action="processform.php" method="post">                        
                <div class="form-label label-name">Nom</div>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                <div class="form-label label-email">E-mail</div>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
                <div class="form-label label-subject">Sujet</div>
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" />
                <div class="form-label label-antispam">Code Anti-Spam</div>
                <input type="text" name="verif" id="verif" size="10" maxlength="6" />
                <div id="verif-box">
                    <img id="captcha" src="securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="Security Code" />
                    <a class="veriflink" href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = 'securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false"><span class="fa fa-refresh"></span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="form-label label-message">Message</div>
                <textarea rows="4" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" id="send" name="button" value="Submit" />           
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- ENGLISH 

    -->

<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/ie-redirect.js"></script>
<script src="js/easing.js"></script>
<script src="js/mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="js/jpreloader.js"></script>
<script src="js/isotope.js"></script>
<!--<script src="js/isotope.fitcolumns.js"></script>-->
<script src="js/imagesloaded.js"></script>
<script src="js/slicebox.js"></script>
<script src="js/hoverdir.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the problem remains... I would like to know how to resolve it but i do not have any idea, i am not an expert in temporary files, caches, etc.

Comment: What's your code look like?

Comment: The codes are long but i edit my question and i copy the codes there... one sec

Comment: I added also additional information in my text : about the folder behaviour...

Comment: Sorry, another info : i can not save the html in Dreamweaver anymore...

Comment: Close and completely end the running Dreamweaver process on your computer. Then reopen it to see if that fixed it. Sometimes a simple reset fixes software issues.

Comment: i closed dreamweaver, i even deleted the cache of it but i still can not open the html file... it uses to come back to normal when i close the computer and come back...
I did not see any dreamweaver exe under the processus tab...

Comment: but even if i end running the processus, it will not resolve the problem, it will come back after a while...

Comment: I can not even open it with notepad

Answer (score 0):

Your missing your `<html>` start tag, `<!DOCTYPE html>` this only declares your doctype. Put the `<html>` tag right after the doctype.

;-)

Comment: you are right, however, i did not declare it in my other html pages either but they work... tomorrow, when i restart my computer and i work with my corrected html page, i will tell you if your solution works or not... thanks !